# Wireless connected but internet not working, modem is fine because I'm typing over wifi on my android

Tags: wireless, networking

I can't connect to the Internet in 11.10.

I tried switching my wifi card to another USB slot but nothing changed. Is it possible that the card is able to connect while not being able to receive packages?

```
$ ifconfig

eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 40:61:86:35:11:b0  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
          Interrupt:43 Base address:0x6000 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 74:ea:3a:8c:d5:5c  
          inet addr:192.168.2.5  Bcast:192.168.2.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::76ea:3aff:fe8c:d55c/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:12 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:102 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:1209 (1.2 KB)  TX bytes:15329 (15.3 KB)
```

Comment: Yes it's possible to be connected to your network and have no internet connection. What /sbin/ifconfig and ping www.google.com gives?

Comment: I cant ping google -unkown host

Comment: And the result of /sbin/ifconfig ?

Comment: Ill try ro edit post .seems that i cant post large texts in comments over my phone

Comment: What happens if you do this: ping 173.194.34.211

Comment: When i use nm-tool state of wlan0 is connected,speed is 40mps.it is a default interface. driver is rt2800usb

Comment: Its pinging with 56(84) bites of data and it stays pinging .Ill tell you if it finishes but i doubt it

Comment: No need to finish, you can cancel it with CTRL+C. Do you have packages lost? Maybe your problem is that you need to set up the dns ip, so it can translate names (www.google.com) to ip addresses.

Comment: Ill try to do it and get back to you

Comment: Try adding the ip of your router to the /etc/resolv.conf file: 
nameserver 127.0.0.1

Comment: Can you link me a guide to do it.but if that what youre speaking is correct shouldnt i be able to connect to google via ip adress.i tried changing resolve.conf and i changed nameservers to 8.8.8.8

Comment: My router ip wad already added.i changed it back to it now.maybe my wifi card isnt working

Comment: Ignore the post above the last one,i didnt saw your comment

Comment: If you can ping 173.194.34.211, then you must have some card working.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to know what ip is your router, if you have dhcp it should be something like this:

192.168.2.5 - Your IP

192.168.2.1 - Your router ip address (i'm just guessing)

Then edit the resolv.conf file:

> sudo vi /etc/resolv.conf

Add the line

> nameserver 192.168.2.1

Save and exit

Try:

> ping -c 3 www.google.com

---- Another solution

Edit the resolv.conf file:

> sudo vi /etc/resolv.conf

Add the lines

> nameserver 8.8.8.8
>
> nameserver 8.8.4.4

Try

> ping www.google.com

If that doesn't work, reboot your pc

Comment: i cant ping google still,what a mess.i would update my pc via my ethernet in living room if there was no other solution

Comment: Do you know your router ip? Can you ping it?

Comment: Yes i can ping it and the ip is 192.168.2.1

Comment: Yes i know my router ip and i xan ping it

Comment: I believe you have a dns problem, i updated my answer with another solution, please try it

Comment: Cant ping google, second command doesnt work but nvm because restarting doesnt help.

Comment: Updated my answer, and please post the contents of your resolv.conf

Comment: nameserver 192.168.2.1

Comment: Put nameserver 8.8.8.8

nameserver 8.8.4.4

Comment: Doesnt work,I have already tried rhat 2 times

Answer (score 0):

You do in fact seem to have a DNS problem, easy way to check is, right click onthe network manager applet, edit connections, go to wireless, wlan0, IPv4 Settings and add 8.8.8.8 to additional DNS servers